# canvas.bind() - Configure width not working (Frame doesn't fill canvas)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, frame, scaling

I've just managed to configure a scrollbar to properly scroll these widgets, but I'm still having an issue with the **frame** not fitting the **canvas**.

I have a bunch of labels that fill out a frame, but the frame doesn't stretch to fill the canvas in the way I want it to.

There was a solution to this on another question that suggested using **.bind()** and '<Configure' (see code) to have the canvas resized to fit the frame (I think), but there are two problems with that:

1. It's not working.
2. I want the frame to stretch to the canvas, not the canvas to shrink to the frame.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Pictures and relevant code below.

Thank you!

[image: picture showing highlighted frame and canvas]

```
def list_talent():
    global new_button, map_button, scrollbar, results_canvas, active_tab, results_frame
    results_canvas.destroy()
    scrollbar.destroy()
    new_button.destroy()
    map_button.destroy()
    results_frame.destroy()
    active_tab = ''

    results_canvas = Canvas(root, width=1080)
    results_canvas.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=7)

    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=results_canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=4, column=8, sticky=N+S)

    results_frame = Frame(results_canvas)
    results_frame_id = results_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=results_frame, anchor="nw")

    def frame_width(event):
        canvas_width = event.width
        results_canvas.itemconfig(results_frame_id, width=canvas_width)

    results_canvas.bind('<Configure>', frame_width)

    new_button = Button(root, text='New', font=('Times New Roman', 12), command=new_record)
    new_button.grid(row=5, column=0)

    map_button = Button(root, text='Map', font=('Times New Roman', 12))
    map_button.grid(row=5, column=7)

    results_title = ['ID', 'Name', 'Profession', 'City', 'Date Signed', 'Phone Number', 'Quick Note']
    for index, text in enumerate(results_title):
        res_title_label = Label(results_frame, text=text)
        res_title_label.grid(row=0, column=index)
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM talents")
    result = mycursor.fetchall()
    for index, x in enumerate(result):
        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[10])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=0, padx=10)

        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[0])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=1, padx=10)

        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[2])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=2, padx=10)

        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[7])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=3, padx=10)

        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[11])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=4, padx=10)

        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[2])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=5, padx=10)

        results_label = Label(results_frame, text=x[0])
        results_label.grid(row=1+index, column=6, padx=10)

        edit_button = Button(results_frame, text='E', font=('Times New Roman', 12))
        edit_button.grid(row=1+index, column=7)

        view_button = Button(results_frame, text='V', font=('Times New Roman', 12))
        view_button.grid(row=1+index, column=8)

    results_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    results_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: results_canvas.configure(scrollregion=results_canvas.bbox("all")))

    active_tab = 'Talent'
```

Comment: If you set different colors to root, canvas and the frame, you will see the width of frame is resized to that of canvas.  It is those labels and buttons inside the frame not occupy all the horizontal space of the frame.

Comment: Ah... thank you. Guess I should stop being lazy and wasting everyone's time! Off the back of that then, how would you recommend I space the labels out to fill the canvas?

Comment: You can try adding `results_frame.columnconfigure(index, weight=1)` inside the for loop of creating the headings.